# Group theory - simple subset proof

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_{1}, G_{2}, G_{3}, G_{4}$ be four finite subgroups of the group $G$.

Is $(G_{1}\cap G_{3}) \circ (G_{1}\cap G_{4}) \subseteq G_{1} \cap (G_{3}\circ G_{4})$ true?

My attempt:

Let $x \in (G_{1}\cap G_{3}) \circ (G_{1}\cap G_{4})$ then $x = ab$ where $a\in G_{1}\cap G_{3}$ and $b\in G_{1}\cap G_{4}$. From this we conclude $x\in G_{1}$ and $x \in G_{3}\circ G_{4}$ and hence  $(G_{1}\cap G_{3}) \circ (G_{1}\cap G_{4}) \subseteq G_{1} \cap (G_{3}\circ G_{4})$ is true.

I think this is the right way to do it. My concern is that this exercise is taken from a book where they have the assumption that $G$ is Abelian and I don't use this assumption here.

Comment: What does that little circle mean?

Comment: Your statement has $G_1\cap (G_3\cap G_4)$ on the righthand side, while what you actually prove is with $G_1\cap (G_3G_4)$.  So something is not right.

Comment: The circle just denotes $G_{1}\circ G_{2}= G_{1} G_{2}$. I have edited the question.

Comment: You're still one edit away from having something true:  You want the last $G_3\cap G_4$ to be $G_3G_4$.  Now the question is, was that the question you actually meant to ask?  Since you had $G_3\cap G_4$ more often than $G_3G_4$, I assumed you really meant what you first wrote.

Comment: @TaraB: May I ask you friend to take a look at mine below? Thanks

Comment: @BabakS.:  It doesn't look like an answer to the question to me, so should be a comment if anything.  I think Gerry asked about the $\circ$ because it's not usual notation (though it may be in some countries for all I know).  Usually we just write $GH$ rather than $G\circ H$.

Comment: Besides to @Gerry's; think about the case you set $\times$ instead of $\circ$. In fact we can speak about the LHS of $$(G_{1}\cap G_{3}) \times (G_{1}\cap G_{4}) \subseteq G_{1} \cap (G_{3}\times G_{4})$$ but what about the RHS? Does it have any meaning? $\circ$ should be introduced completely.

Comment: Perhaps the book assumes $G$ is abelian because if it isn't then $G_1G_2=\{{\,rs\mid r\in G_1,s\in G_2\,\}}$ is not necessarily a group.

Comment: @Gerry: yes, I think that's probably why.  You might as well add that to your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I have to express my concern about whatever happened to $G_2$!

The proof provided looks completely right to me. If you want to be completely explicit, you could include some additional steps, e.g. after the first sentence you could insert

"So $a\in G_1$ and $b \in G_1$, therefore $x = ab \in G_1$, since $G_1$ is a subgroup of $G$. Also, $a\in G_3$ and $b \in G_4$, therefore $x = ab \in G_3 \circ G_4$"

The inclusion can be strict; consider $G_1 = \langle(1,1)\rangle,G_3=\langle(0,1)\rangle,G_4=\langle(1,0)\rangle$ sitting inside $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

One more thing: you don't need the finiteness condition, as you can easily check.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: OP has edited question so what follows is no longer relevant.

I'm not sure what that little circle is, but I don't see why $G_3\circ G_4$ should be a subset of $G_3\cap G_4$.